# Jquery, set value of an element with on click event on a container element

Tags: jquery, function, events, click, fancybox

Here is my problem,

i'm using jquery FancyBox, and i'd like to set value of an input (into my box) with the id of the element clicked !

BUT, my element is made this way :

```
<a... ID="xxxx">
    <i/> <i/>
</a>
```

My a tag is my container, it contains 2 small pictures... (with font-awesome) these small pictures have NO id! SO,
if i click somewhere on my container, i get my value as i want... BUT IF I CLICK ON ONE OF THESE IMAGES, the event.target.id is empty because it's using the image id instead of the container id...

here is the code for the "caller element" :

```
<a class="btn btn-info add" href="#addNewPopup" title="Add Data" id="addData'.$g["id"].'User'.$u["id"].'">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
</a>
```

and here is the js code i use to check my system (#hiddenInput is the input type hidden which is into my fancybox, my fancybox is called with the href="#addNewPopup" on the a link before...) :

```
$(".add").click(function(event){
    $("#hiddenInput").val(event.target.id);
    alert("CONTENT OF ID : "+($("#hiddenInput").val()));
});
```

this is certainly an "easy" thing to solve... but can't get it!

Thanx for any help! :)

(PLEASE don't tell me there is syntax error on my a link id, it's PHP code i just copy-pasted here, so my '' and "" may look like mistakes... ! :) )

Comment: cant you just check for an empty target id and then search for a parent element?

Comment: Maybe you should check if `target` is `i`, get `target`'s parent id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this.id` instead of `e.target.id`

```
$("#hiddenInput").val(this.id);
```

The [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property of [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) refers to the element which caused the event to raise, in your case it might be the `i` elements. What you need is to get the `id` of the anchor element, which is referred by `this` or [e.delegateTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/22g0b7o8/)